# bootstrap responsiveness issue on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am working on a website where i am using Bootstrap v3.3.7 . But the issue arises when i go to mobile view the row is going out of the screen width. and causing some issue with the design
my div structure is something like this

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row" id="something">
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="left-side">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-5" ></div>
         <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-7" ></div>
        </div>
  </div>
 <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
     </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

can anyone help me out what is wrong with this structure and why a scroll bar is coming at the bottom of the page ? 
i would like to mention that when i  add

```
#something{margin:0px}
```

then it fixing the issue

sorry i can't share my exact code for some specific reason. ty

Comment: Provide Fiddle?

Comment: `com-sm-4` should be `col-sm-4`

Comment: everything works well with this code.. the problem is in some of your inner elements

Comment: yes sorry i made typo here , but in my code its col. and i would like mention one thing when i put margin left and margin right =0 then it fixing the issue

Comment: Most likely, you have a `.row` as direct child of `<body>` instead of placing it as child of `.container` or `.container-fluid`. The code in your question is irrelevant, since it doesn't reproduce the issue you are describing. Unless you provide a [mcve], don't bother adding code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes for row in bootstrap by default margin from left and right is -15px to cover the area (padding of 15px from left and right of outer div)of left and right of outer div perhaps it may be of container or any col div so if you remove this margin the structure of the site will not aligned and create a scroll bar on the bottom on mobile. So kindly remove #something{margin:0px} on mobile width.
If you want to hide the scroll bar at the bottom add the css:
body(overflow-x:hidden;)

If the is any other problem let me know.